# Base64 conversion decimals

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, language-agnostic, base64

I've been reading about base64 conversion, and what I understand is that the encoded version of the original data will be 133% of the original size.

Then, I'm reading about how YouTube is able to have unique identifiers to their videos like `FJZQSHn7fc` and the reason was: an 11 character base64 string can map to a huge number.

Wait, say a huge number contains 20 characters, then wouldn't a base64 encoded string be 133% of that size, not shorter?

I'm very confused. Are there different types of base64 conversion (string to base64 vs. decimal to base64), once resulting in a bigger, and the other in a smaller resulting string?

Answer (score 1):

Each character in base 64 can encode 6 bits of data. Thus 11 characters can encode 6x11 = 66 bits of data.

```
2^66 = 73786976294838206464
```

73786976294838206464 (approximately 7.4 x 10^19 or 74 quintillion) possible identifiers is more than enough to distinguish unique YouTube videos for the foreseeable future.

It is unlikely that YouTube is using these strings of length 11 as encodings of smaller objects. You can use base64 (just a number in base 64 after all) without having to think of it as an encoding of something else, just like you can use bytes (binary numbers with 8 bits) without thinking of those bytes as being encodings of ascii characters. The only important question with an identifier scheme is if there are enough identifiers to go around. In this case there clearly are.

Comment: How is this different from base64 encoding? Are they totally different concepts?

Comment: This isn't any different. YouTube is encoding an integer (probably a `long int` of 64 bits), and the result is the 11-character string. 11 characters takes up 88 bytes (assuming the characters are encoded in ASCII and use one byte each), which is 133% of 66 bits (you have 2 extra bits in the base64 encoded version since each character encodes 6 bits, and therefore you need 11 characters to fit all 64 bits of your source integer and end up wasting two).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: you have a 64bit number (called **long** in Java, for example).

Now, you can print that number in different ways:

- As a binary number (base 2), printing 64 '0' or '1'
- As a decimal number (base 10), printing up to 20 decimal digits
- As a hexadecimal number (base 16), printing 16 hexadeciaml digits
- As a number in base 64, printing 11 "digits" in that base. You can use any graphical symbols as digits.
- ... you understand by now that there are many more possibilities  ...

It seems like they use the same base-64 numbers as the ones that are used in base64 encoding, that is, uppercase and lowercase letters, ordinary digits and 2 extra chars. Each character represents a 6-bit value. So you get 66 bits, and depending on the algorithm used, either the leading or trailing 2 bits are cut off to get a nice **long** value back.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing what things are being compared.
There are 2 statements, both comparing different things:

1. "base64 encoding is 133% bigger than original size"
2. "An 11 character base64 string can encode a huge number"

In the case of **1**, they are normally referring to a string encoded maybe with ASCII using 8bits a character, and comparing that with the same string encoded in base64. That is 133% bigger, because in base64 you can't use all 255 bit combinations in every byte.

In the case of **2**, they are comparing using a numeric identifier, and then either encoding it as base64, or base10. In this case, base64 is a lot shorter than base10.

You can also think of the (1) case as comparing base256 against base64, and the (2) case as comparing base10 against base64.

Answer (score 0):

When you say Base64, some would think of [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-5). If YouTube is using RFC 4648, then it's a 12-digit number where they're omitting the last digit because it is always '=', the padding character (the 65th element of the base64 alphabet). The 12 digits represent three blocks of four digits, and four digits yield 24 bits of information. YouTube video IDs would therefore be 64-bit, not 66-bit, if they're using the standard.

Those 64 bits might be representing an unsigned integer. YouTube used MySQL and then sharded MySQL through [Vitess](https://vitess.io/), so you could imagine them using an UNSIGNED BIGINT key internally that they encode via RFC 4648-compliant Base64 externally.

Clearly Tom Scott thinks YouTube is squeezing 66 bits out of their 11 characters; his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8) says so.

If he's wrong, then their frontend might allow you to specify four distinct video IDs for the same video. Those two extra bits' values do not affect the UNSIGNED BIGINT. Which two bits they are depend on endianness and other choices of encoding.

Regardless of whether YouTube is using standard or nonstandard encoding, they can represent 18446744073709551615 in 11 characters (since the padding character is always there and and thus omitted for a 64-bit quantity).

Perhaps they use something like the following to compute a pseudorandom 64-bit integer when a new video is created:

```
import base64
import random

def Base64RandomSlug():
  array = bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for x in range(64 // 8))
  b = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(array))
  return b.decode('utf-8').rstrip('=')
```